# gcutil returning "BadStatusLine: '' from gcutil commands copied from console when using cygwin terminal

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcutil

Today I've started to get the line
BadStatusLine: ''
returned when I use Cygwin terminal to run valid gcutil commands

I copy the command to ssh into an instance from the google web console and usually it (eventually) returns asking for my ssh passphase but today its just returning 
BadStatusLine: ''

It also returns that if I try other gcutil commands like to create a new instance but I can't swear the command is correct unlike the ssh google displays which I copy and paste directly into the commandline

Any ideas what the matter could be?

Comment: This error message typically happens when the HTTP client object in gcutil has expired, which happens after gcutil has been running for quite some time.  I've seen this error come up, but only when I let gcutil sit at a prompt for quite a while.  What exact commands are you running, and what does your interaction look like?

Comment: It came up when trying to ssh into an instance but now you say it the gcutil window was open for a while between commands